# Convert float to varchar

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, rounding

I am looking for a function F to convert a float *x* to varchar with a given decimal places precision, *y*.

For every float (x1, x2) F should have the following property:

`Abs(x1 - x2) <= 10^(-y)` implies that `F(x1,y) == F(x2,y)` (where == is the string equality).

I have tried F = `Str(Round(x,y),50)` or `Cast(Round(x,y) as varchar)` but
with  `x1 = -0.000001` and `x2 = 0.000001` we have `F(x1,5) = '-0'` and F`(x2, 5) = '0'`, failing the string equality test.

Using decimals as intermadiary step will open the door to exception when working with large floats (I think).

Any ideas for F?

Sample buggy code:

```
    declare @x1 float = -0.000001;
    declare @x2 float = 0.000001;
    declare @y int = 5;
    PRINT Str(Round(@x1,@y)) -- outputs -0
    PRINT Str(Round(@x2,@y)) -- output 0
```

[Edit 19-04-2015]

I am now testing with `F=Str(Round(@x1+0.0,@y))`
Adding 0.0 is a IEEE 754 trick to get rid of negative zeros.

Adding expected results as per commenter request:

```
F(-0.00001,4) = F(-0.00001,4) = "0"
F(-1,4) != F(1,4)  ("-1" != "1")
F(1.23456,4) = F(1.23457,4) ("1.2346" = "1.2346")
F(1.23454,4) != F(1.23455,4) ("1.2345" != "1.2346")
```

[Edit 20-04-2015]

F=CAST(Round(x + 0.0,y) as varchar) works. Closing question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that ROUND will return a float (based on the input type). The float is not aware of the decimal precision to format and display. 
Use STR to define a length and decimal precision to display without rounding first.

```
DECLARE @x1 float = -0.000001; 
DECLARE @x2 float = 0.000001; 
DECLARE @y int = 5; -- decimal precision
DECLARE @z int = 30; -- total length of string
PRINT LTRIM(STR(@x1,@z,@y)); -- outputs -0.00000
PRINT LTRIM(STR(@x2,@z,@y)); -- output 0.00000
```

The LTRIM will remove the padded spaces at the beginning. Hope that helps.

To remove the sign and just get the scalar value then use the ABS function.

```
DECLARE @x1 float = -0.000001; 
DECLARE @x2 float = 0.000001; 
DECLARE @y int = 5; -- decimal precision
DECLARE @z int = 30; -- total length of string
PRINT LTRIM(STR(ABS(@x1),@z,@y)); -- outputs 0.00000
PRINT LTRIM(STR(ABS(@x2),@z,@y)); -- output 0.00000
```

Comment: But "-0" is different from "0" even if |x2-x1|<=10^-5

I expected the Round function to round up to 0, but the sign is an issue.

Comment: OK that wasn't clear. Can you add the expected result for each input, to the question? 
To remove the sign you can use the ABS function (see edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

`F=CAST(Round(x + 0.0,y) as varchar)` works.